# Cloud correction in QGIS

Tags: qgis, cloud-cover

I have a Landsat 7 scene with many clouds in it. I like to correct it in QGIS.

My supervisor told me to interpolate it with a scene before and a scene after.

I am struggling on how to do that.

Do I use the raster calculator? Do I have to stack them first?

As a result I would like to have a "new" scene with all the bands but without the clouds.

Comment: Didn't you ask the supervisor how to do it? That would be probably the first I would think of.

Answer (score 2):

In general:

Landsat 7 data includes a cloud mask in the QA (quality assesment) band. You can use that band with the [Landsat Quality Assesment Tool](https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-level-1-quality-assessment-tools) to mask out cloud pixels from a time series of images. Then create a new image that is the average of those masked images.

Be aware that getting a totally cloud free image is pretty hard, and you'll need a long time series of images. So your result will have reflectance values from different times.